# wicked_pdf create hyperlinks to local files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I wan't to create a PDF document, which contains hyperlinks to local files. E.g. when the PDF is downloaded, along with some files, the PDF contains hyperlinks to these files. Is this possible to achieve, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following. This method works in general for linking local files to HTML documents.

```
<a href="file:///C:\Programs\sort.mw">Link 1</a>
<a href="file:///C:\Your File Location">Link 2</a>
```

Notice the `file:///` (3 slashes) before the location.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but how do you create relative links with it?